# sqoop2 fail to start

Tags: linux, hadoop

My sqoop2 suddenly die and unable to start since 2 days ago, I have not changed any settings on sqoop2, I checked the /var/log/sqoop2 catalina log it says:

```
Mar 14, 2016 2:06:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib<br>
Mar 14, 2016 2:06:18 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-12000<br>
Mar 14, 2016 2:06:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 2661 ms<br>
Mar 14, 2016 2:06:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina<br>
Mar 14, 2016 2:06:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.44<br>
Mar 14, 2016 2:06:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive sqoop.war<br>
Mar 14, 2016 2:06:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory ROOT<br>
Mar 14, 2016 2:06:33 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-12000<br>
Mar 14, 2016 2:06:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 15277 ms<br>
Mar 14, 2016 2:06:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
SEVERE: StandardServer.await: create[8005]:
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376)
at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:404)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:676)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:628)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)<br>

Mar 14, 2016 2:06:33 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol pause
INFO: Pausing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-12000<br>
Mar 14, 2016 2:06:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stop
INFO: Stopping service Catalina<br>
Mar 14, 2016 2:06:34 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc<br>
SEVERE: The web application [/sqoop] registered the JDBC driver [org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver40] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.<br>
Mar 14, 2016 2:06:35 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol destroy
INFO: Stopping Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-12000
```

Does anyone have any idea?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be the relevant part of the log:

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

Most likely cause is either:

1. sqoop2 is already running (but in a mostly-dead state, not responding or doing anything useful but still running.  i.e. hung rather than crashed).

Check with `ps aux | grep sqoop`.  Kill it if it's running, then restart.

Or:

2. something else is running which is using the same port.  Try running `netstat -tupan | grep :port` (where "port" is the port number sqoop2 wants to bind to).  Kill it and start sqoop2.

Comment: Thanks! I have changed the sqoop admin port from 8005 to something else inside Cloudera Manager and it is working now!